# How to increment and store the value of a variable each time a button is pressed on a python telegram bot

Tags: python, asynchronous, telegram, telegram-bot, dispatcher

Here is my code. Any time I run the code and press a button, it just increments once. For example if press team_1 button it will increment to 11 and keep on printing 11 but I want to increment the variable anytime the button is pressed add and not just one time

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


button1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text= "Team 1", callback_data="team_1")
button2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text= "Team 2", callback_data="team_2")
keyboard_inline = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(button1, button2)

bot = Bot(token='5603608851:AAH5VWjUoK-x_K3LScnIG6rbe87oBblHdrs')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['bet'])
async def option(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Select a team:", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hello! Im Lele bot, Please follow the instruction")

#handler for clicking the buttom objects
@dp.callback_query_handler(text = ["team_1", "team_2"])
async def choice(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    a = 1
    b= 1
    if call.data == "team_1":
        b += 10
        await call.message.answer(b)
    if call.data == "team_2":
        a += 1
        await call.message.answer(a)
    await call.answer()


executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little time and manipulations with global variables and the following option is ready:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

keyboard_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Team 1", callback_data="team_1")
button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Team 2", callback_data="team_2")
button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="result", callback_data="result")
keyboard_inline.add(button1, button2)
keyboard_inline.add(button3)


bot = Bot(token='token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hello! Im Lele bot, Please follow the instruction")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['bet'])
async def option(message):
    global a, b
    a = 0
    b = 0
    await message.reply("Select a team:", reply_markup=keyboard_inline)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " score\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" score")


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def choice(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global a, b
    if call.data == "team_1":
        a += 1
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " score\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" score")
    elif call.data == "team_2":
        b += 1
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " score\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) +" score")
    elif call.data == "result":
        await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "---FINAL SCORE---\n"
                                                     "Team 1 - " + str(a) + " score\nTeam 2 - " + str(b) + " score")
        a = b = 0
    await call.answer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I hope that programmers with experience do not throw stones at me;)

Comment: Thanks but when running the program, and clicking on the button it's showing error that the variables 'a' and 'b' are not defined

Comment: Strange... Maybe you removed some part of the code? What is your python version?

Comment: I'm currently using Python 3.10.4